# Python loop changing appearance of XY plots in Abaqus - issue with one type of axes

Tags: python, abaqus

Thanks to your help I've managed to add looping over all XY plots in Abaqus Viewer to my simple script initially working only on a plot with user-specified name. There's still one small issue though. I run the script and everything is fine apart from the fact that for some reason Y axis for XY plots of force quantities is not changed according to the script (larger bolded font for title and labels). It works for all energy plots. Here's part of the script:

```
for chart_key in session.charts.keys(): 
   session.charts[chart_key].axes1[0].titleStyle.setValues(
   font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
   session.charts[chart_key].axes1[0].labelStyle.setValues(
   font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
   session.charts[chart_key].axes2[0].titleStyle.setValues(
   font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
   session.charts[chart_key].axes2[0].labelStyle.setValues(
   font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
```

I'm not sure what that 0 means next to axes1 (X, I guess) and axes2 (Y, I guess). Maybe that's the problem. I would like that script to work for all types of quantities but energy, force, displacement, velocity and acceleration might be sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

0 in axes1[0] and axes2[0] refers to the bottom X-axis in Abaqus Viewer. The Y-axis is axes2 in Abaqus Viewer. So, axes2[0] refers to the left Y-axis.

To change the right Y-axis you can use axes2[1]. Example of code:

```
for chart_key in session.charts.keys(): 
    # X-axis
    session.charts[chart_key].axes1[0].titleStyle.setValues(
        font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
    session.charts[chart_key].axes1[0].labelStyle.setValues(
        font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
    
    # left Y-axis
    session.charts[chart_key].axes2[0].titleStyle.setValues(
        font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
    session.charts[chart_key].axes2[0].labelStyle.setValues(
        font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
    
    # right Y-axis
    if session.charts[chart_key].axes2Count > 1:
        session.charts[chart_key].axes2[1].titleStyle.setValues(
            font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
        session.charts[chart_key].axes2[1].labelStyle.setValues(
            font='-*-verdana-bold-r-normal-*-*-140-*-*-p-*-*-*')
```

Comment: I see, thank you. But I only want to change the bottom X axis and the left Y axis. So axes1[0] and axes2[0]. My script does it for energy plots but not for force plots for some reason. Do you know what can be the cause?